# How to print the results of True Positives, False Positives, etc

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset (pandas dataframe) which contains spam and ham mails. So the typically machine learning beginner tutorial. I run my model on it to see how my classifier works.

### Source code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC


df = pd.read_csv('TextFiles/smsspamcollection.tsv', sep='\t')

X = df['message']  
y = df['label']    

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train) # Originaler Datensatz wird verwendet!
X_train_tfidf.shape
print(X_train_tfidf)



text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('clf', LinearSVC()),
])



text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)  



predictions = text_clf.predict(X_test)
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
```

### Results

```
[[1586    7]
 [  12  234]]

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test,predictions))

precision    recall  f1-score   support

         ham       0.99      1.00      0.99      1593
        spam       0.97      0.95      0.96       246

    accuracy                           0.99      1839
   macro avg       0.98      0.97      0.98      1839
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      1839
```

As you can see, I have 7 False Positives.

### Question 1

How can i find out which seven messages out of my dataframe are classified as False Positive? And how can I see in general which messages belong to which category of TP,TN,FP,FN ? Is there any function?

### Question 2

How could I improve the results?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i find out which seven messages out of my dataframe are
>   classified as False Positive? And how can I see in general which
>   messages belong to which category of TP,TN,FP,FN ? Is there any
>   function?

### True Positive

Means prediction of your classifier and ground truth label are both `true` (or `1`). You can get a binary mask of those easily with binary `and`:

```
y_test & predicted
```

To get indices of those examples use:

```
np.argwhere(y_test & predicted).flatten()
```

(you can use this snippet for any case below as well)

### False positive

True label is `0`, you incorrectly predicted `1`. It would be this:

```
(y_true == 0) & predicted
```

### True Negative

True label is `0` and you predicted it correctly:

```
(y_true == 0) & (predicted == 0)
```

### False Negative

Groundtruth is `1`, you predicted `0`:

```
y_true & (predicted == 0)
```

> How could I improve the results?

This question is too general for this site (previous one was fine). You could look into grid search and other hyperparameter tuning techniques (see [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)).

Comment: Hi and thanks for fast response!

I have written the code: np.argwhere(y_test & predictions).flatten()

but I get an error message:

ypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'


I don't know how to convert it into ints. 



By "np.argwhere(y_test & predicted).flatten()" i get the indices of an array. So far so good. But how do I get the content if this array?

Also: How do I know that predictions is TP or TN or FP or FN?

Comment: Each formula is for TP, FP, TN and FN respectively. Your predictions should be binary (0 and 1) and so should be your ground truths (`y_test`), no `str` should be involved. After getting TP (or any other) you are left with a binary array with as many entries as testing examples. You can slice `y_test` with it like this: `y_test[y_test & predicted]` to get only True Positive samples from test.